# after running the code the following error is unexpected token<

Tags: jquery, html

I want to fetch some data from external url so I tried to run the following code 
I am getting the error as `unexpected token <`.

```
var req='something'
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    data:{q:req},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Can any body please help me to solve this error?

Comment: most likely data is not json but html/text

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the data you are receiving is not json data instead some error page returned by server. You can alert raw data to confirm same in anonymous function for `success`

```
success: function (data) {
     alert(data)   
     //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
```

Also, while specifying payload its mentioned that

```
data:{q:req}
```

but `q` isn't defined anywhere. I think quotes are missing here, which could result in error response from your server. 
Also look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/